# Подскажите, что я не так написал?

Tags: android, kotlin, jvm

Я написал код, который считает сумму массива массивов. Код рабочий, кроме строки, которую я пометил комментарием.

```
fun main() { 

val list = mutableListOf<Any>() list.add(listOf(3,4,2,
listOf<Any>(34,4,4, listOf(1, 22),221,2212))) list.add(listOf(23,4,2,
listOf<Any>(34,4,4, listOf(1, 22),221,2212))) list.add(listOf(2,
listOf<Any>(34,4,4, listOf(1, 22),221,2212),65,65))
list.add(listOf(3,4,2, listOf<Any>(34,4,4, listOf<Any>(1,
22),221,2212,43,34), 122,212)) list.add(listOf(3,4,2,
listOf<Any>(34,4,4, listOf(1, 22),221,2212)))

 println(resultList(list)) }    

fun resultList(l: List<Any>): Int {

     var result = 0 
   for(row in l){
    if(row is Int && (!(row / 2)))     **//кроме этой строки**
       result += row
        else
        result += resultList(row as List<Any>)
    }
    return result }
```

Если убрать `&& (!(row / 2))`, то код полностью рабочий. Но когда я захотел добавить в параметры if сортировку по делению на 2, код перестал работать. Изначально просто суммировались все числа массива и мне надо сделать так, чтобы суммировались только нечетные числа. В чем проблема кода - я не понимаю, поскольку я написал в параметрах нужную мне задачу.

```
fun main() { 

val list = mutableListOf<Any>() list.add(listOf(3,4,2,
listOf<Any>(34,4,4, listOf(1, 22),221,2212))) list.add(listOf(23,4,2,
listOf<Any>(34,4,4, listOf(1, 22),221,2212))) list.add(listOf(2,
listOf<Any>(34,4,4, listOf(1, 22),221,2212),65,65))
list.add(listOf(3,4,2, listOf<Any>(34,4,4, listOf<Any>(1,
22),221,2212,43,34), 122,212)) list.add(listOf(3,4,2,
listOf<Any>(34,4,4, listOf(1, 22),221,2212)))

 println(resultList(list)) }    

fun resultList(l: List<Any>): Int {

     var result = 0 
   for(row in l){
    if(row is Int)   
       result += row
        else
        result += resultList(row as List<Any>)
    }
    return result }
```

Если код будет выглядеть вот так, то он будет рабочим.

Comment: *"код перестал работать"* и в чем это выражается, как выглядит?

Comment: Unresolved reference: !

Comment: Если я уберу выше указанную строку, то получится результат 13089. То есть я скорее всего неправильно написал синтаксически. Возможно && (!(row / 2)) - этот параметр стоит указать в другом if?

Comment: Добавляйте уточнения в вопрос, кнопка "править". А комментарии после можно и удлаить.

Comment: Спасибо, учту. Я не особо знаю этики этого сайта, поэтому простите.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Кроме синтаксиса, ошибка в том что вы объединили два условия в одно - в итоге блок `else` выполняется и для вложенного массива и для нечётных чисел, что и вызывает ошибку времени выполнения, так как нечётное число не является массивом и код `row as List<Any>` не может быть выполнен

```
fun resultList(l: List<Any>): Int {

   var result = 0 
   for(row in l) {
       if(row is Int) {
           if (row % 2 != 0) {
                result += row
           }
       } else {
           result += resultList(row as List<Any>)
       }
    }
    return result
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Вы мне правда очень помогли. Буду сидеть разбираться в том, что вы написали, чтобы понять в чем моя ошибка. Спасибо огромное еще раз!

Answer (score 0):

Ну если вы проверяете числа на четность в этой строке, то возможно стоит писать :

```
if(row is Int && (!(row % 2 == 0)))
```

Comment: `!(row % 2 == 0)` - нельзя ли сократить `!` и записать `(row % 2 != 0)` ? ;-)

Comment: К сожалению, ответ не помог. Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: @RhaegarTargaryen, "не помог" в смысле компилятор продолжает указывать ошибку синтаксиса или результат не тот, что ожидается?

Comment: Компилятор продолжает указывать ошибку.
Ошибка:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.util.List
 at FileKt.resultList (File.kt:24) 
 at FileKt.resultList (File.kt:24) 
 at FileKt.main (File.kt:14)

Comment: Нет - это уже ошибка времени выполнения. Вам нужно разделить условие на два `if`. Я плохо знаю синтаксис Котлина, но попробую написать ответ - думаю поймёте о чём речь